# Sympy seems to break down with higher numbers

Tags: python, sympy

I've been playing around with sympy and decided to make an arbitrary equations solver since my finance class was getting a little dreary. I wrote a basic framework and started playing with some examples, but some work and some don't for some reason.

```
from sympy import *
import sympy.mpmath as const

OUT_OF_BOUNDS = "Integer out of bounds."
INVALID_INTEGER = "Invalid Integer."
INVALID_FLOAT = "Invalid Float."
CANT_SOLVE_VARIABLES = "Unable to Solve for More than One Variable."
CANT_SOLVE_DONE = "Already Solved. Nothing to do."

# time value of money equation: FV = PV(1 + i)**n
# FV = future value
# PV = present value
# i = growth rate per perioid
# n = number of periods
FV, PV, i, n = symbols('FV PV i n')
time_value_money_discrete = Eq(FV, PV*(1+i)**n)
time_value_money_continuous = Eq(FV, PV*const.e**(i*n))

def get_sym_num(prompt, fail_prompt):
    while(True):
        try:
            s = input(prompt)
            if s == "":
                return None
            f = sympify(s)
            return f
        except:
            print(fail_prompt)
            continue

equations_supported = [['Time Value of Money (discrete)', [FV, PV, i, n], time_value_money_discrete], 
                       ['Time Value of Money (continuous)',[FV, PV, i, n], time_value_money_continuous]]
EQUATION_NAME = 0
EQUATION_PARAMS = 1
EQUATION_EXPR = 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while(True):
        print()
        for i, v in enumerate(equations_supported):
            print("{}: {}".format(i, v[EQUATION_NAME]))
        try:
            process = input("What equation do you want to solve?  ")
            if process == "" or process == "exit":
                break
            process = int(process)
        except:
            print(INVALID_INTEGER)
            continue
        if process < 0 or process >= len(equations_supported):
            print(OUT_OF_BOUNDS)
            continue
        params = [None]*len(equations_supported[process][EQUATION_PARAMS])
        for i, p in enumerate(equations_supported[process][EQUATION_PARAMS]):
            params[i] = get_sym_num("What is {}? ".format(p), INVALID_FLOAT)
        if params.count(None) > 1:
            print(CANT_SOLVE_VARIABLES)
            continue
        if params.count(None) == 0:
            print(CANT_SOLVE_DONE)
            continue
        curr_expr = equations_supported[process][EQUATION_EXPR]
        for i, p in enumerate(params):
            if p != None:
                curr_expr = curr_expr.subs(equations_supported[process][EQUATION_PARAMS][i], params[i])
        print(solve(curr_expr,  equations_supported[process][EQUATION_PARAMS][params.index(None)]))
```

This is the code I have so far. I guess I can strip it down to a basic example if need be, but I was also wondering if there was a better way to implement this sort of system. After I have this down, I want to be able to add arbitrary equations and solve them after inputting all but one parameter.

For example, if I put in (for equation 0), FV = 1000, PV = 500, i = .02, n is empty I get 35.0027887811465 which is the correct answer. If I redo it and change FV to 4000, it returns an empty list as the answer.

Another example, when I input an FV, PV, and an n, the program seems to hang. When I input small numbers, I got RootOf() answers instead of a simple decimal.

Can anyone help me?

Side note: I'm using SymPy 0.7.6 and Python 3.5.1 which I'm pretty sure are the latest

Comment: For numerical solutions you might try `nsolve`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a floating point accuracy issue. `solve` by default plugs solutions into the original equation and evaluates them (using floating point arithmetic) in order to sort out false solutions. You can disable this by setting `check=False`. For example, for Hugh Bothwell's code

```
for fv in range(1870, 1875, 1):
    sols = sp.solve(eq.subs({FV:fv}), check=False)
    print("{}: {}".format(fv, sols))
```

which gives

```
1870: [66.6116466112007]
1871: [66.6386438584579]
1872: [66.6656266802551]
1873: [66.6925950919998]
1874: [66.7195491090752]
```

Comment: Awesome! As a little addon in case anyone was wondering about the second example, sympy tries to find the exact solution, so if n is really high, it gives n RootOf solutions. If you experiment with n = 1 and n = 2, you can see sympy gives answers with sqrt in it. Using nsolve works better

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but I do have a much simpler demonstration case ;-)

```
import sympy as sp

FV, n = sp.symbols("FV n")
eq = sp.Eq(FV, sp.S("500 * 1.02 ** n"))

# see where it breaks
for fv in range(1870, 1875, 1):
    sols = sp.solve(eq.subs({FV:fv}))
    print("{}: {}".format(fv, sols))
```

which produces

```
1870: [66.6116466112007]
1871: [66.6386438584579]
1872: []
1873: []
1874: []
```

At a *guess* this is where the accuracy breaks down enough that it can't find a verifiable solution for `n`?

---

Also, while poking at this I did a fairly extensive rewrite which you may find useful. It does pretty much the same as your code but in a much more loosely-coupled fashion.

```
import sympy as sp

class Equation:
    def __init__(self, label, equality_str, eq="=="):
        self.label = label
        # parse the equality
        lhs, rhs = equality_str.split(eq)
        self.equality = sp.Eq(sp.sympify(lhs), sp.sympify(rhs))
        # index free variables by name
        self.vars = {var.name: var for var in self.equality.free_symbols}

    def prompt_for_values(self):
        # show variables to be entered
        var_names = sorted(self.vars, key=str.lower)
        print("\nFree variables are: " + ", ".join(var_names))
        print("Enter a value for all but one (press Enter to skip):")
        # prompt for values by name
        var_values = {}
        for name in var_names:
            value = input("Value of {}: ".format(name)).strip()
            if value:
                var_values[name] = sp.sympify(value)
        # convert names to Sympy variable references
        return {self.vars[name]:value for name,value in var_values.items()}

    def solve(self):
        values = self.prompt_for_values()
        solutions = sp.solve(self.equality.subs(values))
        # remove complex answers
        solutions = [sol.evalf() for sol in solutions if sol.is_real]
        return solutions

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.equality)

# Define some equations!
equations = [
    Equation("Time value of money (discrete)",   "FV == PV * (1 + i) ** n"),
    Equation("Time value of money (continuous)", "FV == PV * exp(i * n)"  )
]

# Create menu
menu_lo = 1
menu_hi = len(equations) + 1
menu_prompt = "\n".join(
    [""]
    + ["{}: {}".format(i, eq.label) for i, eq in enumerate(equations, 1)]
    + ["{}: Exit".format(menu_hi)]
    + ["? "]
)

def get_int(prompt, lo=None, hi=None):
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input(prompt))
            if (lo is None or lo <= value) and (hi is None or value <= hi):
                return value
        except ValueError:
            pass

def main():
    while True:
        choice = get_int(menu_prompt, menu_lo, menu_hi)
        if choice == menu_hi:
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
        else:
            solutions = equations[choice - 1].solve()
            num = len(solutions)
            if num == 0:
                print("No solutions found")
            elif num == 1:
                print("1 solution found: " + str(solutions[0]))
            else:
                print("{} solutions found:".format(num))
                for sol in solutions:
                    print(sol)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: No, this also happens if you substitute "1.02" with "(102/100)", which stops sympy from using floating point values (verify by looking at the string repr of ``eq``). At that point, it truly is trying to solve the equation symbolically, so it can’t be accuracy I think.

Comment: Wow very nice code. I've learned a lot of interesting idioms :) I've shyed away from classes in python but it proves useful. I'm playing around with nsolve and hopefully it'll turn out better